# headless build with CDT using .cproject configuration

Tags: build, eclipse-cdt, headless

I have a eclipse project with .project and .cproject, and I want automate the building process, for it I use

./eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data /home/user/workspace/ -build App

but it don't use the .cproject file to build, how I make for the building process use the .cproject configuration?

thanks

Comment: Hi, do you mean you would like to build outside of eclipse, while using the build parameters you defined inside eclipse ? If so, use : 'cd Release; make clean && make all' from a shell.

Answer (score 3):

If your project is a makefile project then simply do what Francois said in the comments.

If you are looking at trying to build a specific configuration, it depends on which CDT Version you have, as if you can do that.

By default the headless builder will build ALL configurations specified in the project. At work we have the original CDT 7.0 version and that one did not support building a specific configuration, but I do see in the notes on CDT 7.0 that it does support building a specific configuration. You would do that by using **`-build App/Config`** instead of just **`-build App`**.

(Note: at home I have eclipse with CDT 7.0.2 and that does support the headless build of a specific configuration as above, although the usage info still doesn't show support for it, and the upcoming CDT 8.0 does correctly show the usage information).